# How to group by RDD values Scala, Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have below scala program which reads a Couchbase bucket from a view and prints the results shown.

```
object CouchReader {

    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        ...
        // Generate The Context
        val sc = new SparkContext(cfg)

        sc.couchbaseView(ViewQuery.from("Document", "activityView"))
        .map(_.key)
        .collect()
        .foreach(println)
    }
}
```

This is the output

```
[35,4,-1]
[35,4,-1]
[35,4,10]
[61,4,1]
[61,4,10]
```

But, I need to get the output grouped by 1st and 2nd element and sum the 3rd element.

i.e my desired output is

```
[35,4,8]
[61,4,11]
```

How can I achieve that?

I am still learning scala & spark, spent some time on map, groupby but seems difficult to get it going.

Answer (score 2):

```
rdd
 .map { case (v1, v2, v3) => ((v1, v2), v3) } // restructure to make v1 + v2 key
 .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```